# Floating action button causing memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, floating-action-button

I have an app am working on, the app is using `leak canary` to detect `possible memory leaks`. The app seems to be fine except for my `extended floating action button`, according to `leak canary` the button is leaking, I do not have an idea on how to rectify this.

Below is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.store.StoreFragment">


    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_margin"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/normal_elevation"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlayLargeCutLeftTopCorner">

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nestScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <ViewStub
                        android:id="@+id/layoutCategories"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inflatedId="@+id/panel_layoutCategories"
                        android:layout="@layout/store_layout_categories" />


                    <ViewStub
                        android:id="@+id/layoutDeals"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inflatedId="@+id/panel_layoutDeals"
                        android:layout="@layout/store_layout_deals" />


                    <ViewStub
                        android:id="@+id/layoutCollections"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inflatedId="@+id/panel_layoutCollections"
                        android:layout="@layout/store_layout_collections" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnGoToCart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:text="@string/cart"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:elevation="@dimen/large_elevation"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_24px"
        app:iconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/nestScrollView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlayLargeCutLeftTopCorner" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my Java code

```
public class StoreFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
  btnGoToCart.setOnClickListener(this);
     }



  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
                ....
            case R.id.btnGoToCart:
                Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.cartFragment);
                break;
                ....
                }
              }
}
```

Below is a snippet from leak canary. At first the `leak` was pointing to the ID of the `coordinator layout`, I removed it, now it is pointing to the `Extended floating action button`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the Fragment implement OnClickListener why not just create a new OnClickListner inner class? From what I see you ar passing the fragment as the OnClickListener and the view later holds a reference to your fragment and that's probably the cause of the leak. Just do (new OnClickListener () {}); instead of implementing OnClickListener.

EDIT:
I've just noticed that you are using ButterKnife in a Fragment.
If your using ButterKnife in a Fragment you should use:

```
private Unbinder unbinder;

@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    // TODO Use fields...
    return view;
}

@Override public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    unbinder.unbind();
}
```

> BINDING RESET Fragments have a different view lifecycle than
>   activities. When binding a fragment in onCreateView, set the views to
>   null in onDestroyView. Butter Knife returns an Unbinder instance when
>   you call bind to do this for you. Call its unbind method in the
>   appropriate lifecycle callback.

Comment: I have the same problem as described in the question. I tried the new OnClickListener (v -> doSomething() as a lambda expression) but it still showed the leak in Leak Canary.